# Use GraphEdt to render a video and have the output appear as brand new capture devies/filters?

Tags: filter, directx, video-capture, directshow

I have a basic video file renderer filter graph made with **GraphEdt**.  Right now, it just sends the audio and video to the default output devices.  Instead, I want to output the stream in a way that makes a brand new input capture device entry, but I don't know how to do this.  In other words, when I run the filter graph, I want a new capture device to show up in the browser's device selection menu; one for the audio and one for the video.  I also want to be able to set the name that is shown the input device list.

For example.  I would like to have one instance of GraphEdt that when I run it, I see in the audio input device menu an entry named "GraphEdt Audio from Video File 1", and when I select a WebCam device input device, I see an entry in the available device list that says "GraphEdt Video from Video File 1".  So if I select one of those filters, I see/hear the audio/video stream being output from the filter graph.

The reason I need this configuration is because I am writing some video conferencing software and I need to simulate multiple streams of audio/video during testing.  Obviously chasing down a bunch of people just to help me do a test isn't feasible.  By having multiple filter graphs running, each with a difference device name, I can test my software just by having a bunch of looping videos taking the place of actual conference participants, one video for each filter graph instance, acting as a "virtual" conference participant.

Can I pull this off with GraphEdt and if so, how?

[image: Filter Graph - Render Video from a File]

Comment: You cannot do this with just GraphEdit. What you need is a "virtual video camera" filter which creates that additional input recognized by various software. The details, complexity and pitfalls of such filters were discussed too many times. That is, I can do this once again, sure, but I assume the whole task is a bit too complicated and if you need this for testing you probably want to check out some third party software which has some similar option, such as virtual camera software or some OBS or something.

Comment: @RomanR.  Ok, thanks.  I spoke with Eugene, the author of Virtual Audio Cable.  He suggested it might be possible with to do it by automating a DirectShow graph with GraphEdt or Graph Studio, but perhaps that's for DirectShow wizards only.  I can't find any 3rd party software that does this.  XSplit Broadcaster will do it for one video source at a time and that's it.  Their tech support told me that they were unaware of any 3rd party software that does this.

Comment: Video and audio parts are pretty much differnt in the aspect of the raised question. Audio can be duplicatied more or less easily with the help of Eugene's driver. This does not apply to video at all, for example the image attached to the question might suggest the opposite and it would be a false assumption.